# ASP.NET Caching in a web cluster

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-caching, asp.net-cache

We are building a large scale web platform where we try to use Caching to speed up things - though now it's a single server, we'll probably upgrade it to a cluster. Will the Caching work there? Should we consider anything special?

Thanks1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a distributed cache. You can find [implementations](http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com/) for different caching providers such as [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx).